# something went wrong when pushing to github with webstorm

Tags: windows, git, bash, github, webstorm

As is shown in the image,I'm not sure if the failure is caused by some missing property while setting up webstorm .
The issue is not resolved after a lot of efforts.As a learner,I don't know what to do now.

[image: cant finish github]

Meanwhile,something seems wrong as shown in git bash.I've no idea whether the two are directly related.

[image: wingw32]

If you have ever faced these difficulties,could you please give me some idea? Even if it's only a web address.

What I want to do is only pushing my code. Anyone who pushed successfully in any other way will be welcomed to share your method.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm being honest I'm not sure that I completely understand your question, but I will supply some information that will hopefully lead you down the right track.

First in the bash shell, `cd` (change directory) into your project directory like this:

```
$ cd /c/foo/bar/yourprojectfolder
```

In your project top most directory, do you have a `.git` folder?  You may have to show hidden folders in windows to see this directory.  If not, you need to initialize a repository with the `init` command.

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/foo/bar/yourprojectfolder/.git/
```

After running this command, you should see a `.git` folder inside of the directory you changed to (used `cd` to get to) earlier.

Next, in order to `push`, you first need a remote repository to push to.  Based on your first picture, I believe that you have successfully created a repository on GitHub.  If not however, just log into [GitHub](http://www.github.com) and click the 'New Repository' button:

[image: Github new repository button]

Once a repo has been created, you need to add it as a remote to your local git (in git bash).  To do this you need a url (either SSH or HTTPS) to your repo.  You can find this url inside of your repository in online [GitHub](http://github.com).  If you are not certain you have set up SSH, it's best to use the HTTPS url.  It should look something like this, but the url itself will be different and specific to your repository:

[image: Github]

Copy that url to your clipboard, and then back in git bash run:

```
$ git remote add origin <PASTE YOUR URL HERE>
```

You need to make an initial commit of your code to have something to push:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Finally, with the origin repo set up and a commit made, you should be able to push to your origin repo

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

You should now be able to view your code on [GitHub](http://www.github.com).